# Hostfile for Email Addresses in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, email

I maintain a Continuous Integration Server running Cruise-Control with the PHPUnderControl plugin. There appears to be a built-in feature that emails build results to users who committed changes to the modification set. It uses the usernames from our SVN server and sends the email there. The problem is, the usernames are not email addresses so it ends up sending emails to `john`, `paul`, and `harry`. I know I can configure CC/PHPUC to send emails to specific addresses but it would be nice if it only sent messages to those who committed to the changeset.

Is there a way I can configure Ubuntu (karmic) to *hostfile* these names to their real email addresses?

```
john   john@address.com
harry  harry@address.com
paul   paul@address.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want `/etc/aliases`.

The basic syntax is like this:

```
john:   john@address.com
harry:  harry@address.com
paul:   paul@address.com
```

for a mailing list:

```
salesdepartment: john,harry,paul
```